# Bootstrap 4 modal does not open in my vue project

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-4

So I'm attempting to use the default modal they give on the website(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) but it doesn't seem to work out of the box for me. There appears to be a "display: none" on the modal class when I run it. I copied the other css properties into my own class but it still fails to load whenever I have the fade class included.. If I remove that it shows, but it doesn't have the black background customary with modals. This feels wrong and I'm inclined to thing there is a problem with my particular version of bootstrap, which I have 4.3.1. Or maybe this is jquery related? Is this a common issue people have seen?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using jquery-component in Vue environment directly can cause porblems because jquery and Vue both manipulates DOM by their own ways. Try to use https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Comment: You have to treat the modal as a component. So create a data property showModal, for instance and make the modal appear when you click that button.

Comment: Just wanna point out you linked `v4.0` docs while mentioning you're using `v4.3.1`